# Crash in production when using a WebBrowser inside a Pivot

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, webbrowser-control

I know it is a bad idea to put a WebBrowser inside a Pivot/RadSlideView control.
I did so anyway:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="**.HtmlView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Style="{StaticResource LeafPageNavigationStyle}">

    <controls:Pivot x:Name="Html" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
                    Style="{StaticResource HeaderlessPivot}">
        <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <phone:WebBrowser Source="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Basically I want to use the Pivot to slide through an array of HTML docs at URIs I provide via my ViewModel, which just wraps an the array in a Caliburn.Micro OneActive Conductor:

```
namespace DSBMobile.ViewModels
{
    public class HtmlViewModel : Conductor<Uri>.Collection.OneActive
    {
        private readonly IUnburyableState<Uri[], HtmlViewModel> _state;

        public HtmlViewModel(IUnburyableState<Uri[], HtmlViewModel> state)
        {
            _state = state;
            Items.AddRange(_state.State.ForceGetValue());
        }
    }
}
```

That runs pretty well in debug and release versions I deploy manually. The App passes all tests imposed by the Store, but as soon as I try to open this specific view within the app, it crashes without any chance to redirect to a Telerik MessageBox.

As soon as I remove the outer Pivot and adjust the ViewModel accordingly, it runs smoothely. As I a said, the crash only happens in production. The Application.UnhandledException handler can't get the app to swallow the exception and display the error.

This is really intricate and bugs me since months. Can anyone resolve this error or point me in a worthwhile direction? I would also appreciate a more WP-ish suggestion for displaying multiple Web links that works.

Comment: UnhandledException doesn't swallow the exception? Have you tried adding BugSense or so to get a stack trace? Also, does it always crash in production, on multiple devices?

Comment: Can you add a minimal [non-]working example? (A zipped solution that crashes.) P.S.

Comment: @sibbl: UnhandledException is called, but cancelling the crash via `e.Cancel = false;` doesn't work. Consequently, no error handling view  is shown after the handler is called for that specific exception. It crashes only in Production, on multiple devices (WP7 as well as WP8) upon opening that specific view.

Comment: A stack trace would be helpful. You could start an EmailComposeTask with the exception inside...

Comment: @Ark-kun: It's hard and time consuming to reduce it, in particular because I have to mail each new version to my employer, who basically hired me for a one-shot task. I understand that the error most probably depends on the surroundings I use and will hopefully be able to post a minimal project within the next days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that I got an UnauthorizedAccessException, explaining that I was missing the ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT capability, which I wasn't. That confused me, until I finally had a look at the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431797(v=vs.105).aspx):

> When you create a WebBrowser control in XAML, you must specify a value for the P:System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Name property for that control so that the Windows Phone Capability Detection Tool can properly detect and grant the right capabilities for your app. For more info about the Windows Phone Capability Detection Tool, see How to determine app capabilities.

With the x:Name set, I could finally have a crashless experience.
For me personally, this was the most annoying bug, ever. It helped that I could upload beta versions in the store although I didn't pay any developer fee, which I hadn't known in beforehand.

TLDR: RTFM.

Comment: And thanks to all people trying to help after I set a bounty. I would share it with all of you, if this was somehow possible.

Comment: btw bro if you delete your question, you will get back your bounty ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I'm not *that* keen on my spent rep... Especially since the question actually got people's attention afterwards.